# Send Mail via Xpages - does not work with blank in NotesName

Tags: xpages, sendmail

I'm trying to send Mails in a javascript library while clicking on a button in a specified xpage. This works fine es long es I use web mail adresses like "testuser@gmail.com".

As soon as I try to use our Notes names, I won't receive any mails. 
I tried "Development/COMPANY/DE" - that worked.
I tried "Firstname Lastname/COMPANY/DE" - that doesn't work anymore.

That's my code:

```
var mail = new HTMLMail();
mail.setTo( receiver );
mail.setSubject( subject );
mail.addHTML( bodyText );   
mail.send();
```

while the variable receiver is: Firstname Lastname/COMPANY/DE

In my script library from [Mark Leusink](http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/m.leusink/entry/send_html_mails_from_an_xpage_with_only_5_lines_of_code?lang=en) the Notes name is still correct:

```
if (this._to.length>0) {
  mimeHeader = mimeRoot.createHeader("To");
  mimeHeader.setHeaderVal( this._to.join(","));
}
```

mimeHeader.getHeaderVal() delivers the exact format Firstname Lastname/COMPANY/DE

But I don't receive any Mails. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Obviously, the space is the problem. Probably expand/split bug in that JS library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the user email from the person document.

```
function getPersonEmail(person){
            var nab:NotesDatabase=session.getDatabase(database.getServer(),"names.nsf")
        var nview:NotesView=nab.getView("($NamesFieldLookup)")
        var doc:NotesDocument=nview.getDocumentByKey(@LowerCase(@Name("[CN]",person)),true)
        if(doc){
             var email = doc.getItemValueString("InternetAddress")
                 doc.recycle()
                 nview.recycle()
                 nab.recycle()
             return @LowerCase(email)
        } else {
         nview.recycle()
         nab.recycle()
         return ""  
        }

}
```